# How to send message to another computer in Workgroup

Tags: delphi, message, lan

I am using Delphi XE3.

I want to send Message to another PC in workgroup (LAN connection). How can I do it? And what Component should I use?

Comment: Check if this [link](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=617) helps you.

Comment: Please dont use irrelevant filler information in the question text instead of indication of some research efforts done. In pre-Vista environments you could use [mailslot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa365576) named [`messngr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Messenger_service). Please read both articles completely.

Comment: A reference for Guillem Vicens's suggestion above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa370605

Comment: @Guillem the link your reference says "This function is not supported as of Windows Vista because the messenger service is not supported", which suggests that this may not be broadly supported solution.

Comment: what version of Windows?

Answer (score 2):

Hey I remember my old days we use to do this

Write this on command prompt:

```
net send  [machine name]  your message
```

this works with smile :)

If machine name doesn't work then try with ip.

Just check if you are using Directory Services then permission of cmd command and well as `net send` command should be there. If no Directory services, this works like a charm.

Comment: While you explain how to do it from the command line, the OP asks how to do it from Delphi. Anyway, a good way to test if it is available

Comment: Messenger Service is disabled by default since Windows XP SP2 and is not supported at all since Windows Vista and Server 2008. So the chances are high no one will see a message sent with `net send`.

Comment: oh, thanks, but i am using Delphi code, not cmd, but can I use ShellExecute ?

Comment: I use Win8 and didn't sucess when I had tried with your code in CMD

Comment: just like u been told, since WinXP the messenger is default off. So you would have to install some chat program onto all your computers.